# Get raw bytes of a float in Swift

Tags: swift, bitwise-operators, ieee-754

How can I read the raw bytes of a `Float` or `Double` in Swift?

Example:

```
let x = Float(1.5)
let bytes1: UInt32 = getRawBytes(x)
let bytes2: UInt32 = 0b00111111110000000000000000000000
```

I want `bytes1` and `bytes2` to contain the same value, since this binary number is the Float representation of `1.5`.

I need it to do bit-wise operations like `&` and `>>` (these are not defined on a float).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update for Swift 3:** As of Swift 3, all floating point types
have `bitPattern` property which returns an unsigned integer with
the same memory representation, and a corresponding `init(bitPattern:)`
constructor for the opposite conversion.

*Example:* `Float` to `UInt32`:

```
let x = Float(1.5)
let bytes1 = x.bitPattern
print(String(format: "%#08x", bytes1)) // 0x3fc00000
```

*Example:* `UInt32` to `Float`:

```
let bytes2 = UInt32(0x3fc00000)
let y = Float(bitPattern: bytes2)
print(y) // 1.5
```

In the same way you can convert between `Double` and `UInt64`,
or between `CGFloat` and `UInt`.

---

*Old answer for **Swift 1.2** and **Swift 2:*** The Swift floating point types have a `_toBitPattern()` method:

```
let x = Float(1.5)
let bytes1 = x._toBitPattern()
print(String(format: "%#08x", bytes1)) // 0x3fc00000

let bytes2: UInt32 = 0b00111111110000000000000000000000
print(String(format: "%#08x", bytes2)) // 0x3fc00000

print(bytes1 == bytes2) // true
```

This method is part of the `FloatingPointType` protocol
to which `Float`, `Double` and `CGFloat` conform:

```
/// A set of common requirements for Swift's floating point types.
protocol FloatingPointType : Strideable {
    typealias _BitsType
    static func _fromBitPattern(bits: _BitsType) -> Self
    func _toBitPattern() -> _BitsType

    // ...
}
```

(As of Swift 2, these definition are not visible anymore in the
API documentation, but they still exist and work as before.)

The actual definition of `_BitsType` is not visible in the API
documentation, but it is `UInt32` for `Float`, `UInt64` for
`Double`, and `Int` for `CGFloat`:

```
print(Float(1.0)._toBitPattern().dynamicType)
// Swift.UInt32

print(Double(1.0)._toBitPattern().dynamicType)
// Swift.UInt64

print(CGFloat(1.0)._toBitPattern().dynamicType)
// Swift.UInt
```

`_fromBitPattern()` can be used for the conversion into the other
direction:

```
let y = Float._fromBitPattern(0x3fc00000)
print(y) // 1.5
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for Swift 2.1

Comment: @Qbyte: I have double-checked the code with Xcode 7.1.1 and 7.2 beta 3. Apart from the necessary change "println" -> "print", everything compiled and worked as expected. – What error  do you get? Which Xcode version are you using?

Comment: That's odd... it works now. But cannot find the excerpt of the `FloatingPointType` protocol, especially `func _toBitPattern()`.

Comment: @Qbyte: You are right, it is not visible anymore in the API documentation, but it still works.

Comment: It seems to me more like a hack since you cannot discover it anymore except on this site :) So is the use of `unsafeBitCast` "safer" than `_toBitPattern` since it is a official global function?

Comment: @Qbyte: An "officially unsafe" function :)! – I leave that for you to decide ... (Perhaps I'll ask in the Apple Developer forum tomorrow.)

Comment: @Qbyte:  What I like is that _toBitPattern/_fromBitPattern "know" the corresponding integer type, so `let bytes1 : UInt16 = Float(1.5)._toBitPattern()` would not compile. `let bytes1a = unsafeBitCast(Float(1.5), UInt16.self)` compiles but throws a runtime exception.

Comment: @Qbyte: As of Swift 3, the conversion methods are public, no "hack" anymore!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unsafeBitCast`, like this:

```
let x = Float(1.5)
let bytes1: UInt32 = unsafeBitCast(x, UInt32.self)
let bytes2: UInt32 = 0b00111111110000000000000000000000
if (bytes1 == bytes2) {
    println ("Success")
}
```

The above prints `"Success"` when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

Could not get this to work:

```
let x = Float(1.5)
let bytes1 = x.bitPattern
print(String(format: "%#08x", bytes1)) // 0x3fc00000
```

or this:

```
let bytes1: UInt32 = unsafeBitCast(x, UInt32.self)
```

So I went for this:

```
print(String(x.bitPattern, radix: 2))
```